String Values for Use as a Parameter in SSRS
I'm creating a report in SSRS and I need to parameterize the building addresses which are unfortunately string data type.
Can someone help me?
The more detailed explanation the better.
I have tried to create a parameter specifying an address column as the specified value, but every way I tried created a drop down with every instance of the same address listed individually.
Any help is appreciated or if someone knows a good detailed SSRS Parameter reference I would appreciate it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A [mcve] is a great start when (if?) asking for SQL assistance.

Explain what you want the users to see and do with the parameters and what you want the report to do with that info. At the moment it's just not clear. It sounds like you misunderstand SSRS parameters though.

I got several comment responses, but they were all critiques of my question. I did not provide a reproducible example because as I said I tried several different ways to achieve the result I was looking for, and was hoping for some general direction if not a specific answer. I don't mean to sound ungrateful. I suspected the answer was not very complex and that it was mostly my own lack of knowledge and experience responsible. In the end I didn't use any of the code I had tried up to that point. I pivoted to a simpler approach.
I wanted to create a parameter from a string. That string was a series of building addresses. I wanted that parameter to filter the results to only entries in the table that had that address.
The user selects the address, and the report shows all entries that have that address.
The way that I solved this issue, was by creating a parameter named BuildingName, and using Specify values. Once I had the values specified, I created a dataset filter [BuildingName] (text) = [@BuildingName] and simple as that it worked.
I had been hoping to make it somewhat more dynamic, and either use some form of the distinct values from that column as the values, or some kind of wildcard evaluation of them.
Anyways it worked in this case because there was a very finite number of possible results, but I would be interested if people know of better and more dynamic ways to approach string-based parameters.
Most of the ways I tried just listed an instance of the address for every entry in the table that had that address.
For instance I was able to write multiple SQL statements that would return the exact values I wanted, but when I included them in the dataset's broader SQL statement, and used them as a parameter they would return repeating values for every address.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
